# Nested object and serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I have like this,

```
Class P {
pub int id;
pub P(id) { this.id = id; }
...
pub Set<Integer> parentTTList;

}

Class TT {
pub int id;
pub TT(id) { this.id = id; }
pub List<P> manyPList;
}

List<TT> manyTTList;

Then TT tA = new TT(1), tB = new TT(2);
P pX = new P(-1), pY = new P(-2);

tA.manyPList.add(pY); pY.parentTTList.add(tA.id);

tA.manyPList.add(pX); pX.parentTTList.add(tA.id);

tB.manyPList.add(pY); pY.parentTTList.add(tB.id);
```

Then use ObjectOutputStream to serialize tA and tB to a byteArray, how many times do we have pY in byteArray? Calss P and TT have many to many relation and we have too many of them so worried about size.

Answer (score 5):

Serialization is smart enough to reuse any references it has seen already so you should only have a single `pY`. This is somewhat explained in this [slightly related FAQ.](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#handle)